# Do you know 1024 Overriding a function error on flex (flash )in action script 3?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

In my project i used this below function

```
    public function createIconMenu():NativeMenu{
        var iconMenu:NativeMenu = new NativeMenu();
iconMenu.addItem(new NativeMenuItem("", true));//Separator
        if(NativeApplication.supportsSystemTrayIcon){
            iconMenu.addItem(showCommand);
            showCommand.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onShowCommand);      
            iconMenu.addItem(new NativeMenuItem("", true));//Separator      
            var exitCommand: NativeMenuItem = iconMenu.addItem(new NativeMenuItem("Exit"));
            exitCommand.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, exit);   
        }       


            return iconMenu;
    }

    public function exit(event:Event):void{
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
    }
```

but on this public function exit shows error like
1024: Overriding a function that is not marked for override.

what did i wrong code ? . could u explain me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the `exit` function to something else. This is colliding with another function in the global namespace that is provided by the system and cannot be overridden by the user.

Comment: if u rename exit function then not working  exitCommand.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, exit);

how to exit  NativeApplication ..

Comment: i got it . thank you so much dirkgently . it's very useful to me

Answer (score 1):

Reset.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, play);

function play(event:MouseEvent):void {
gotoAndPlay(1);
}

I got the same problem with this simple code